# int' object is not subscriptable when calling pandas apply function

Tags: python

I am facing issue with doing rather simple thing with `pandas` apply function. I have a dataframe, which has respondents' `age` column (`type - np.int64`). I want to create a new column that would `group age by categories`, like `18-25`, `26-35`, `36+`.

I thought that the best way is to write a function and then apply it to the dataframe. However, I am permanently getting this error :

> 'int' object is not subscriptable'

I have tried many options, like `int()`, `astype(int)` and so on.

I have read all other stuff about `__getitem__ attribute`, but I do not understand why it is now working. I am just simply getting an integer value, make conditional comparison and tries to assign a string to a column.

Here is my function:

```
def group_by_age(row):
    data = row['age_response']
    if ((data['age_response'].astype(int)) > 18) & ((data['age_response'].astype(int)) < 26):
       row['age_grouped'] = '18-25'
    elif ((data['age_response'].astype(int)) > 25) & ((data['age_response'].astype(int)) < 36):
       row['age_grouped'] = '26-35'
    elif (data['age_response'].astype(int)) > 35:
       row['age_grouped'] = '36-45'
return row
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: `data = row['age_response']`, so what is `data['age_response']` supposed to be? Does your `row` variable have 2 dimensions with the same specifier??

Answer (score 0):

If you pass your `group_by_age` to `apply` then the problem is that `apply` passes a single element to the function (in your case, an int). So `row` inside `group_by_age` is an int, then `row['age_response']` raises the `'int' object is not subscriptable'` exception.

In any case I think you have over engineered the solution.

```
import pandas as pd

def group_age(x):
    if 18 <= x <= 25:
        return '18-25'
    if 26 <= x <= 35:
        return '26-35'
    if x >= 36:
        return '36-45'

df = pd.DataFrame({'age': [18, 30, 25, 36, 20]})

print(df)
>>    age
   0   18
   1   30
   2   25
   3   36
   4   20

df['group'] = df['age'].apply(group_age)

print(df)

>>   age  group
  0   18  18-25
  1   30  26-35
  2   25  18-25
  3   36  36-45
  4   20  18-25
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I have definitely overthought the issue:)